# How to implement input auto-tab in React (focus on next input element on keyup event)?

Tags: reactjs

Using React as library, I have several blocks of input text, each one with maxlength=1, and I would like to implement a function that everytime a character is entered in an input box the focus goes to the next one.

This is the list of input elements I'm talking about:

[image]

And this is a minimal representation on CodesSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autotab-6kewb.

How can I get the desired behaviour in React?

This is the relevant snippet:

```
const autoTab = e => {
  const BACKSPACE_KEY = 8;
  const DELETE_KEY = 46;

  if (e.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEY) {
    // TODO: implement backwards autoTab
  } else if (e.keyCode !== DELETE_KEY) {
    // TODO: implement forwards autoTab
  }
};

const blocks = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (element, index) => (
  <input className="block" key={index} maxLength={1} onKeyUp={autoTab} />
));
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippet to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added tab indexes to your input elements and used them to navigate between items.

```
const autoTab = e => {
  const BACKSPACE_KEY = 8;
  const DELETE_KEY = 46;
  let tabindex = $(e.target).attr("tabindex") || 0;
  tabindex = Number(tabindex);
  if (e.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEY) {
    tabindex -= 1;
  } else if (e.keyCode !== DELETE_KEY) {
    tabindex += 1;
  }
  const elem = $("[tabindex=" + tabindex + "]");
  if (elem[0]) {
    elem.focus();
  }
};

const blocks = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (element, index) => (
  <input
    className="block"
    tabIndex={index}
    key={index}
    maxLength={1}
    onKeyUp={autoTab}
  />
));
```

EDIT: Here is a new way using refs and the [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autotab-zl4be) based on your code sandbox.

```
const autoTab = e => {
  const BACKSPACE_KEY = 8;
  const DELETE_KEY = 46;
  let tabindex = $(e.target).attr("data-index") || 0;
  tabindex = Number(tabindex);
  let elem = null;
  if (e.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEY) {
    elem = tabindex > 0 && elemRefs[tabindex - 1];
  } else if (e.keyCode !== DELETE_KEY) {
    elem = tabindex < elemRefs.length - 1 && elemRefs[tabindex + 1];
  }
  if (elem) {
    elem.current.focus();
  }
};

const Input = props => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  elemRefs.push(ref);
  return (
    <input
      className="block"
      data-index={props.index}
      ref={ref}
      maxLength={1}
      onKeyUp={props.autoTab}
    />
  );
};

const blocks = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (element, index) => (
  <Input key={index} index={index} autoTab={autoTab} />
));

const App = () => <div className="App">{blocks}</div>;
```

Comment: This works but the behaviour is achieved by jQuery, not by React. Isn't it possible to get this behaviour using only the React library?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you can change the third line to:
```let tabindex = e.target.getAttribute('index');```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ref to focus on next element, you can use index along with your ref name to distinguish element

like this:

```
this.refs[yourrefname].nextSibling.focus();
```

and your input element should have ref with unique name

```
<input ref={yourrefname + index} className="block" key={index} maxLength={1} onKeyUp={autoTab} />
```

Comment: The "this" you're talking about is the context of the React class component, right? In my case I have a function component, so probably I would use a useRef hook instead but I'm not aware exactly how.

Comment: yes, i am talking about class component but you can create in functional component see link, 

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I know I can, the question is how :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a simple CSS selector

```
const autoTab = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (`${e.target.value.length}` === e.target.getAttribute("maxlength")) {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("autotab");

      for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (e.target == inputs[i]) {
          i++;
          if (i < inputs.length) {
            let next: any = inputs[i];
            next.focus();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          className="autotab"
          type="text"
          maxLength={1}
          onChange={(e) => {
            autoTab(e);
          }}
        />
    </>
  );
```